# Where to save shell scripts on FreeBSD so that they are added to the path?

Tags: bash, sh, freebsd

I have a fairly simple .sh script that can be ran on FreeBSD by the command `bash clearlogs.sh arg1`. The script takes an integer parameter and simply curses through specified directories and deletes files older that a specified time which is identified as the 1st argument. I was wondering if there was a best practice location to save .sh files as well as the proper way to add them to the path so that any user could simply type `clearlogs 7` and that script runs.

Comment: `echo $PATH`. One of those folders. Rename it `clearlogs`. Also, linux is not freebsd. So that's a bad tag combo.

Comment: Also, remember that Bash is not installed by default on FreeBSD. You have to install it manually (`pkg install bash`).

Answer (score 1):

Most programs installed by a local administrator go under `/usr/local/bin`. This way you can be sure that your script is not going to be discarded during an upgrade. Also, make sure that the script is executable.

You may also consider creating a port for your own use. See the [Porter's Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/porters-handbook/book.html#quick-porting) for more details. It might be a little bit of an overkill, however.